# Shell command not executing my .py file from vb.net

Tags: python, vb.net, execute

I wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction.
I am trying to write a `VB` application that runs a simple python program of about 10 lines , then is supposed to return to `VB` and wait for the excel file that `xyz.py` created to read a cell from it.

**Problem** I cannot get the file to execute.

I have tried

```
 Shell("C:\Users\Clive\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe C:\Users\Clive\Documents\xyz.py")
```

also:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Users\Clive\Documents\xyz.py")
```

none of these work.
before we carry on double clicking `xyz.py` gives me a correct result as well as running from the command line.
Am I missing a reference or something?

thanks in advance!

Clive

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using should work fine. But this worked for me

```
Shell("py C:\fakepath\xyz.py")
```

If py is not in your PATH environment you can find it at C:\Windows\py.exe

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.
First a python3 script to generate a csv file:

```
import csv
with open('order.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['name', 'amount'])
    writer.writerow(['ham', '3'])
    writer.writerow(['egg', '2'])
exit(1)
```

Then a vb app to call the python script and read the generated csv file:

```
Imports System.IO
Module App
    Sub Main()
        Process.Start("C:\Projects\PythonVbInterop\PythonVbInterop\script.py").WaitForExit()
        For Each line In File.ReadAllLines("Order.csv")
            Console.WriteLine(line)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```